# Installed RVM and tried to switch ruby version but no go

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
mlanza@mlanza-desktop:~$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/mlanza/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
mlanza@mlanza-desktop:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
```

This is on Ubuntu 10.4 where 1.8.7 was already installed.  Does RVM require that all Ruby versions be installed by it?

Do I have to set a PATH variable in my .bashrc?

Comment: You restart your shell after installing rvm?

Comment: Yes. I did restart.  I kept looking and I think I got it...

Answer (score 1):

```
mlanza@mlanza-desktop:~$ rvm rvmrc trust
Marked /home/mlanza/.rvmrc as trusted
mlanza@mlanza-desktop:~$ [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
mlanza@mlanza-desktop:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

is the last thing in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Also, reading the "[Post install](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)" docs might help, especially the troubleshooting section. However, usually we see people haven't added the above line to their startup script, or they've forgotten to set the default Ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

RVM doesn't require or expect that all Rubies on your system are under its control. Mac OS X includes Ruby for its own purposes, and RVM allows it to be used by issuing `rvm use system`. At that point RVM steps out of the way until you tell it to use one of its managed Rubies.